# Python + Selenium Dropdown issue

Tags: python, forms, firefox, selenium

I have the following code

```
select = row.find_element_by_css_selector("select")
select.click()
opts = select.find_elements_by_css_selector("option")[1:]
Select(select).select_by_visible_text(choice(opts).text)
```

Actually, the form field drops down, and a random element flashes. So it seems working. But! It doesn't select the element. No JavaScript events are triggered, and the form field, or at least the rendered form field remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the select HTML element to the Select object:

```
select = Select(row.find_element_by_css_selector("select"))
select.select_by_index(1)
```

The `Select` has a number of different (and convenient) ways to choose what you are trying to "select": http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html

FYI, I'm not sure what your `choice()` is doing, but by index may be less error prone (and more robust). Also the `click()` is unnecessary.

Comment: `choice` is a random pick-one method. So it just picks a random instance .

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem: it it impossible to select an option from a dropped-down field. So, removing the fist `click()` solves the problem. I'm not sure that this behaves the same in each browser, but in Firefox, you can't do this.

This is not handled very well in Selenium, because it doesn't raise any exceptions.